# SAP HANA: how to get the list of dates from system using SQL hana where the date range is from '2019-10-24' and CURRENT_DATE

Tags: hana

how to get the list of dates from system using SQL hana where the date range is from '2019-10-24' and CURRENT_DATE

Comment: [`SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', date '2019-10-24', current_date)`](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html)

Comment: Please follow Stack Overflow tag guidelines. For SQL tag: "If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." As you are not interested by answers about "ISO/IEC standard SQL" which would say that it's not possible, you should not use tag SQL. Same for tag DATABASE: "If it is about a particular database management system, (e.g., MySQL), please use that tag instead." I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is the [SERIES_GENERATE_DATE](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html) table function:

```
SELECT *
FROM SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '2019-10-24', CURRENT_DATE)
```